# how to set cakephp 3 email unique validation

Tags: validation, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I created a table users with 2 fields id(primary),(email)
I want email unique validation used following code but not working only not empty working.

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;
use App\Model\Validation\UserValidator;
class UsersController extends AppController
{
public function register()
{
$this->loadModel("users");  
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
$validator = new UserValidator();
$errors = $validator->errors($this->request->getData());
 if (empty($errors)) {

      } else {
        $this->set('errors', $errors);
      }
}
}
}
```

src/Model/Validation/UserValidator.php

```
<?php 
namespace App\Model\Validation;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;
use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\ORM\Rule\IsUnique;
class UserValidator extends Validator {
  public function __construct()
  {
  parent::__construct();
    $this
    ->notEmpty('name', 'The name field cannot be left empty')
    ->notEmpty('email', 'Fill Valid Email Id')
    ->add('email',['unique' => ['rule' => 'validateUnique', 'provider' => 'table', 'message' => 'Not unique']])
    ->notEmpty('mobile', 'Fill Valid 10 Digit Mobile No.');
  }
}
```

Comment: i guess cakephp 3 as you tagged is now using table

Answer (score 2):

create this file under \src\Model\Table\Userstable.php

**updated**

change the the filename capitalize the to make it  \src\Model\Table\UsersTable.php

in my code below I validated my username and email as unique

```
use App\Model\Entity\User;
use Cake\ORM\Query;
use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;
use Cake\ORM\Rule\IsUnique;
/**
 * Users Model
 *
 */
class UsersTable extends Table
{

    /**
     * Initialize method
     *
     * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);
        $this->table('users');


    }

    /**
     * Default validation rules.
     *
     * @param \Cake\Validation\Validator $validator Validator instance.
     * @return \Cake\Validation\Validator
     */
    public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
    {



       $validator
        ->requirePresence('username','create')
        ->notBlank('username', 'A username is required')
        ->add('username', 'unique', [
                    'rule' => 'validateUnique',
                    'provider' => 'table',
                    'message' => 'Username is already used'
             ]);


       $validator
        ->requirePresence('email','create')
        ->notBlank('email', 'An email is required')
        ->add('email', 'unique', [
                    'rule' => 'validateUnique',
                    'provider' => 'table',
                    'message' => 'Email is already used'
             ]);





 return $validator;

    }


    public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
    {
       $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['username']));
       $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['email']));
        return $rules;  

    }

}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class UsersTable in \src\Model\Table\Userstable.php on line 76

Comment: in what line causing the error ? "Cannot redeclare class UsersTable "   then comment it temporarily